# Different bootstrap behaviour on localhost and development server environment

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with modals of bootstrap 3.0.0 and jQuery 1.10.1.

At some point of my website I need to show a form inside a modal, and I want that form to be like a form wizard. To do so I use a [formToWizard pluggin](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/turn-any-webform-into-a-powerful-wizard-with-jquery-formtowizard-plugin/) (well, it is not a plugin but it is what I need).

I call it as follows, so it works on initially loaded forms, and also on forms inside modals.

```
    $("form.form-steps").formToWizard();
    $("#modal").on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
        $(this).find("form.form-steps").formToWizard();
    });
```

This **works perfectly fine in localhost**, however in production environment (I use Heroku) it doesn't.

Using Chrome's inspector I noticed some things:

- First, when I open the modal for the first time the event is triggered, so a breakpoint in the 3rd line of my excerpt above stops the execution. **I can go step by step until the form is transformed into what I want**. However, while returning from inner functions, I see that at some point (inside jquery) it gets stuck (like in an infinite loop).

  I imagine that without going step by step, this would occur asynchronously and the error would come before the
- Second, when instead of going step by step, I open the modal for the first time, and **resume the execution, the form is not transformed**. The weird part is that opening the modal a second time no longer stops in the breakpoint.

**Why is this working differently on production?** Since it is a front-end library I thought I should work the same way.

#### UPDATED

As requested, I duplicated my app, and remove the login system to provide an example of the error. [Here it is](http://jsbug.herokuapp.com/).

There, both buttons show the same form. The one displayed as a modal doesn't convert the form into a wizard (and doesn't display the slider properly either). The form displayed at full view works as it should.

If you use the inspector, you'll notice the issues I explained before.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to answer this question without a live example, but to my experience the main difference with localhost and production is "race conditions" and cache. Your application will be slower downloading resources and if not done correctly there might be some code running before it should. Also be sure to turn off the cache checking your production environment as it might not have discovered all changes to your new production code.

Please provide a link to your production environment, maybe the answer can be found in the source code.

I would also suggest logging out the event being triggered. Is it the event being triggered multiple times or is it the actual "formToWizard" method call that is causing the loop.

I am also a bit confused that you are calling "formToWizard" before the event and when it triggers.

Comment: Ok, I just duplicated my app and prepare it (strip the js, remove the login system, add dummy home page) so you can check the code

Comment: Hi, there is not problems using Chrome on the page you added. I opened the form several times, it seems to work just fine?

Comment: That's really strange. I tried with a couple of pc/browsers and it didn't work. What is your chrome version?